# shift right operator on strings in c#

Tags: c#, file, architecture, bit-shift

I have a stream reader object "file" and a character type variable "hex"

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);

char[] hex=new char[20];
int @base;
```

the code i want to implement is

```
        string line;
       while ((line=file.ReadLine()) != null) //Reading each address from trace file
        {

            if (@base != 10)
            {          
               line >> hex;  
                 ///this line giving errors, as shift right cannot be implemented on string types
                address = changebase(hex, @base);

            }
            else
                line >> address;
```

I am making a cache memory hit and miss project.
But in c# shift right cannot be applied to string variables, so any other option to implement the line of code .. Please any help

Any other way to implement this line

Comment: First decide on language. Which one `c#` or `c++` ?

Comment: @I4V c# language, i am using

Comment: First explain what you think a `shift right` operator should do with a string as left hand operand and an array of char as right hand operand .

Comment: Looks like you come from a C++ background. Operator overloading hacks are not normally being done with C#.

Comment: no i have a text file, of traces of main memory addresses, that are to be held in cache.

Comment: In your context, what is: changebase? address ? Can your give us an example of how the file looks like and what you expect as a result?

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can only overload the operators `<<` and `>>` when one of the operands is an `int`, so this type of code is strictly off limits.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt18et0d.aspx):

> User-defined types can overload the `>>` operator; the type of the first
>   operand must be the user-defined type, and the type of the second
>   operand must be `int`. For more information, see [operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s53ehcz3.aspx).

The reason why you cannot do this is because the language designers did not want you to, and I certainly can't fault them. `line >> hex` might look cool, but it does the same thing as `line.Insert(hex)` and is usually much less descriptive of what actually happens.

Comment: i have used the insert method as line.Insert(0,Convert.ToString(hex));

Comment: @HanyaIdrees: It's meant entirely as an example. I cannot suggest a real world stand-in because I have no idea what your code is trying to do.

Comment: @HanyaIdrees: I also have no idea what "start index" means in this context. Please edit your question and provide lots of additional information.